# How to remove docker which was install from binaries?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I installed a docker-ce (version 18.06) in my Ubuntu 16.04 from binary which introduced in this page[1](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/).

Now I want to remove it and reinstall docker-ce by apt.
But I don't know how to remove it...
I just know remove the things which I copy to /usr/bin..
Any other thing should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to reinstall docker because I want to install nvidia-docker and I found all guides recommend installing by apt... so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, stop dockerd: `sudo systemctl stop docker`
- Then, remove the docker binaries you've installed. If you copied the binaries to `/usr/bin` then `sudo rm /usr/bin/docker*`

Comment: But when I try to 'sudo apt-get install docker-ce' after done what you said, It tells 'docker-ce is already the newest version (18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu)'

Comment: I'm confused why apt said I have installed docker-ce? install docker-ce from binary shouldn't modify any apt file, right?

Comment: It seems you have docker-ce installed as well. Just remove the package by using "apt-get remove docker-ce -y"